# MS Word VBA to display Unicode strings

Tags: vba, unicode, ms-word, persian, farsi

We have some VBA code in MS Word 2010 which needs to display Persian (Farsi) words dynamically; in other words, depending on which buttons the user clicks on the VBA app window, we will display a different string of Persian.

The only way we discovered to do this was to use something like this and concatenate a very long string character by character: `the ChrW(&633)`. Do you know another way we can do this? The strings will remain the same, but we need a couple of different ones. Can they be loaded from a file?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean _display_? In the document, in a MesageBox or in a form?

Comment: To display it in a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets have an UTF-8 text file *unicode.txt*, a form *UserForm1* with label *Label1* and Button *CommandButton1*:

```
'ensure reference is set to Microsoft ActiveX DataObjects library 
'(the latest version of it) under "tools/references"

Dim adoStream As ADODB.Stream
Dim var_String As Variant

Set adoStream = New ADODB.Stream

adoStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
adoStream.Open
adoStream.LoadFromFile "unicode.txt"

Label1 = adoStream.ReadText

adoStream.Close
```