# How to save a Unicode character to a text file

Tags: vba, macos, unicode, ms-word, character-encoding

This is in Word for MAC VBA. I want to save the Unicode character from a text box to text file. For example this character "⅛".

I use this code.

```
Dim N as Long
N = FreeFile
Dim strText as String
strText = Textbox1.Text 'This is what is in the textbox "⅛"
Open <file path> For Output As N 
     Print #N, strText
Close N
```

It does not save the Unicode character. I understand I have to change the text encoding format. How do I do that?

Likewise, how to read the text file with the Unicode format?

Comment: Please write which special character (char code? font? unicode?).

Comment: I a bit busy now. But I will get back. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your patients. I changed the entire content. Please read it.

Answer (score 11):

I hope this will fit VBA for Word on Mac as well, but on Windows I have the CreateTextFile method of the FileSystemObject (see [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)). There I can define to create a unicode text file.

```
  Set fsObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set xmlFile = fsObject.CreateTextFile("path/filename.txt", True, True) 'the second "true" forces a unicode file.

  xmlFile.write "YourUnicodeTextHere"
  xmlFile.close
```

Comment: This way you can create a file with unicode coding, but **not in UTF-8** with byte order mark and so on. UTF-8 is not only unicode - see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8). The only way in VBA, what I know, is with ADODB.

Comment: OP asked for Unicode. He did NOT ask for UTF-8 with byte order mark.

Comment: Oops, you are right. I've edited my answer for Unicode coding. Results are equal. - However, ADO method has more possibilities in coding, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 7):

VBA can't code text in UTF-8 this way. Use ADODB - yes, for text, not for database.

```
'ensure reference is set to Microsoft ActiveX DataObjects library
'(the latest version of it) under "tools/references"
Sub AdoTest()
    Dim adoStream As ADODB.Stream
    
    Set adoStream = New ADODB.Stream
    
    'Unicode coding
    adoStream.Charset = "Unicode" 'or any string listed in registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Charset
    
    'open sream
    adoStream.Open
    
    'write a text
    adoStream.WriteText "Text for testing: ěšč", StreamWriteEnum.stWriteLine
    
    'save to file
    adoStream.SaveToFile "D:\a\ado.txt"
    
    adoStream.Close
End Sub
```

Reading is simplier, see my answer here:

[Unicode and UTF-8 with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17699668/2369384)

Edited: I've inserted complete example.

Edited 2: Added refernce to list of coding in the registry

Answer (score 3):

The question is for VBA on Mac, and I'm afraid none of the answers work on a Mac.

The question is about *Unicode* which comes in many flavours. I'll address the UTF-16 aspect of it. UTF-8 follows a different path, but it isn't difficult too. AFAIU, your question is about UTF-16 string.

The code below has no error handling, I'll let you take care of that.

```
Function writeUnicodeTextToFile(filePathName As String, myText As String)

`Dim myFileNumber As Long, I As Long, byteArray() As Byte

myFileNumber = FreeFile()
Open filePathName For Binary As #myFileNumber

ReDim byteArray(1)

' Create a BOM for your Unicode flavour
' (CHOOSE! one of the two, programmatically, or hard-code it)
 ' => Little Endian
    byteArray(0) = 255: byteArray(1) = 254
' => Big Endian
    'byteArray(0) = 254: byteArray(1) = 255

' now write the two-byte BOM
Put myFileNumber, 1, byteArray

' redimension your byte array
' note it works even if you don't Redim (go figure) but it's more elegant
I = (LenB(myText) / 2) - 1
ReDim byteArray(I)

' populate the byte array...
byteArray = myText

' ... and write you text AFTER the BOM
Put myFileNumber, 3, byteArray
Close #myFileNumber
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, can you just briefly explain what needs to be adapted for UTF-8 export? Thx

Comment: It's more complicated. You need a VBA function to convert from plain text to UTF-8. Once that is done, you must first write a 3-byte BOM, then write data to disk as 8-bit text (ANSI).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Since those are unavailable on a mac, perhaps, as the answerer specified

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA routine that takes a string as input (your text), and fills an array of bytes. Then you write that array to disk in binary mode, making sure you start writing it **after** the first three bytes (BOM).

You'll need those Public variables:
byteArray() As Byte, regexUTF8 As String

Sub testing()

' creating the BOM

Dim bom(2) As Byte, someFile As Long

bom(0) = 239: bom(1) = 187: bom(2) = 191

' Writing something as utf-8
UTF16toUTF8 "L'élève de l'école"

someFile = FreeFile()
Open "MacDisk:test.txt" For Binary As #someFile
' first, the BOM
Put #someFile, 1, bom
' then the utf-8 text
Put #someFile, 4, byteArray1
Close #someFile
End Sub

Sub UTF16toUTF8(theString As String)

' by Yves Champollion
' Transforms a VB/VBA string (they're all 16-bit) into a byteArray1, utf-8 compliant

```
    If isStringUTF8(theString) Then Exit Sub

    Dim iLoop As Long, i As Long, k As Long

    k = 0
    ReDim byteArray1(Len(theString) * 4)
    For iLoop = 1 To Len(theString)
        i = AscW(Mid$(theString, iLoop, 1))
        If i < 0 Then i = i + 65536
        If i > -1 And i < 128 Then
            byteArray1(k) = i
            k = k + 1
        ElseIf i >= 128 And i < 2048 Then
            byteArray1(k) = (i \ 64) Or 192
            byteArray1(k + 1) = (i And 63) Or 128
            k = k + 2
        ElseIf i >= 2048 And i < 65536 Then
            byteArray1(k) = (i \ 4096) Or 224
            byteArray1(k + 1) = ((i \ 64) And 63) Or 128
            byteArray1(k + 2) = (i And 63) Or 128
            k = k + 3
        Else
            byteArray1(k) = (i \ 262144) Or 240
            byteArray1(k + 1) = (((i \ 4096) And 63)) Or 128
            byteArray1(k + 2) = ((i \ 64) And 63) Or 128
            byteArray1(k + 3) = (i And 63) Or 128
            k = k + 4
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve byteArray1(k - 1)

End Sub
```

Function isStringUTF8(theString As String) As Boolean

```
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    ' Prime the regex argument
    If Len(regexUTF8) <> 66 Then
        regexUTF8 = "*[" + Space$(62) + "]*"
        For i = 192 To 253
            Mid(regexUTF8, i - 189, 1) = Chr(i)
        Next
    End If

    ' First quick check: any escaping characters?
    If Not theString Like regexUTF8 Then Exit Function

    'longer check: are escaping characters followed by UTF-8 sequences?
    For i = 1 To Len(theString) - 3
        If Asc(Mid(theString, i, 1)) > 192 Then
            k = Asc(Mid(theString, i, 1))
            If k > 193 And k < 220 Then
                If (Asc(Mid(theString, i + 1, 1)) And 128) Then
                    isStringUTF8 = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
            If k > 223 Then
                If (Asc(Mid(theString, i + 1, 1)) And 128) And (Asc(Mid(theString, i + 2, 1)) And 128) Then
                    isStringUTF8 = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
            j = j + 1
            If j > 100 Then Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```