# Converting a UTF-8 w/o BOM to ASCII CP852 encoding in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have several files encoded with UTF-8 w/o BOM that I need to convert to ASCII CP852 encoding using VB6.

Can anyone help me to do it in VB6.

Comment: For reading/writing unicode and UTF-8 files is the best way to use ADO - yes, for text files, not for databases. See my earlier posts: [reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17699668/2369384) and [writing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18982841/2369384).

Comment: Once you have the UTF-8 converted to UTF-16LE ("Unicode") via ADO Stream you can convert that for output by using `.Charset = "ibm852"` or the equivalent alias `.Charset = "cp852"` as already described in a comment under another answer for another question you posted this question to.

Comment: you mean I have to convert it a couple of times?

Comment: Hi Bob, i tried that but it always come back to Windows(ANSI). Im successful in converting to unicode but after i convert to ibm852 it output is Windows (ANSI), can you share with me how to do it in codes, thanks