# VB6 load unicode string as 'ChrW$ (&H410)' etc from txt file

Tags: unicode, vb6

I have a long Unicode string saved in Unicode encoding from notepad, in this form

```
ChrW$ (&H410) & "   " & ChrW$(&H430) & vbNewLine & ChrW$(&H42F)
```

etc, to end of file

If I assign the above code as the value of an Ink Edit box in code, it displays the correct Unicode chars, which is what I wanted.

But for some reason I can't find the right way to open the text file and get that to display the Unicode chars. This is probably very simple, but I've got totally confused.

What is a simple way of achieving this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file has the Unicode text and not VB expressions as you showed... not much to it:

```
Dim F As Integer
Dim Text() As Byte

F = FreeFile(0)
Open "SomeUnicode.txt" For Binary Access Read As #F
'File is UTF-16LE, so we'll skip the BOM:
ReDim Text(LOF(F) - 3)
Get #F, 3, Text
Close #F
InkEd.Text = Text
```

Otherwise you'll need an expression evaluator, and you could use the Microsoft Script Control to process such expressions if you drop the $ *type decorators*.

Comment: Apart from the file names and comments, thats the same code I was using before, with the exception of 'Binary Access Read As'... It now works fine, puzzled why it didnt before. Thanks!

Comment: @moorea21, don't be so selfish, you could at least accept his code

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: I suspect he is just referring to the "mark as accepted answer" box or something.  Not a big deal to me but it seems to be considered proper in here.

Comment: Thanks Bob77, it certainly helps when someone explains themselves properly. Done

Comment: You can read UTF8 coded text files with ADO (yes, text files, not database files), see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698260/ms-word-vba-to-display-unicode-strings/17699668#17699668). Very easy, very correct.